# Call Servlet and return response with ajax (JQuery)

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, response

I begin in Servlet and I don't understand my problem.
I call a Servlet thanks JQuery and I want the Servlet returns data to JS.

My JS Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://localhost:8080/hello/servlet',
    data:'{field:"abc"}',
    type:'post',
    cache:false,
    success:function(data){alert(data);},
    error:function(){alert('error');}
}
);
```

and My Servlet:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet{
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
        {
  //Do nothing  import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        //Do nothing
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String field = req.getParameter("field");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");


        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("You entered \"" + field + "\" into the text box.");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

The servlet returns nothing...
What's the problem?

FYI, when I go to localhost:8080/hello/servlet in the browser, it works.

Comment: How comes that when you access `localhost:8080/hello/servlet` it works? What exactly do you mean by: it works? Accesing an url would automatically send a HTTP request on GET method , but your `doGet` method does nothing.ALso, are you sure you have correctly mapped your servlet in your `web.xml` deployment descriptor?

Comment: `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");` Doesn't this mean you won't allow any header but Content-Type?  What would be the point of doing this?

Comment: also `data:'{field:"abc"}',` shouldn't that be `data:{'field':'abc'},`? You're not using the `'` right I don't think.

Comment: Daniel: In fact the method doGet is the same of the method doPost. It works because I see what I want: when I am in localhost:8080/hello/ I see a form who redirect in localhost:8080/hello/servlet who executes the method doPost.

developerwjk: I don't know what it means, I copy/paste from a website, I thought it was good. Thanks for the error, maybe this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: I corrected the two errors ("field" & delete setHeader("Access-Control-Akkiw-Headers"...)). 
When I execute, I have a warning: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/hello/servlet".
FYI, I add filter cross-origin in web.xml.